# Show DIV based on condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have following declarations in my jsp page:
where b3 is a cable instance mapped in struts action class.

```
    <s:set var="b3unit" scope="request" value="b3.cableunit"/>
    <s:set var="b3sid" scope="request" value="b3.cableid" />
    <s:set var="b3tube" scope="request" value="b3.btube"/>
    <s:set var="b3fiber" scope="request" value="b3.bfiber"/>
    <s:set var="b3id" scope="request" value="b3.cable_user_id" />
    <s:set var="b3name" scope="request" value="b3.cable_name" />

 <%  String b3 = (String) request.getAttribute("b3sid");
        String b3_type = "Cable";
        String b3_id = (String) request.getAttribute("b3id");
        String b3_name = (String) request.getAttribute("b3name");
        int b3_tube = (Integer) request.getAttribute("b3tube");
        int b3_fiber = (Integer) request.getAttribute("b3fiber");
        float b3_tot_height = b3_tube * b3_fiber * 10.8f;
        float b3_tube_sec_height = b3_tot_height / b3_tube;
```

%>

and a dynamic DIV :

```
<div  class="type_b" style="margin-left: 1300px; margin-top:-<% out.print((height * 11) + 100);%>px ;  height: <% out.print(height);%>px">
                <div class="section" style="float: right; margin-left: 55px; height: <% out.print(height);%>px">                        
                    <div id="cable_3" class="cable" style="margin-top: <% out.print((b3_tot_height/2)+b_tot_height);%>px"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="section" style="float: right; margin-left: 55px; height: <% out.print(b3_tot_height);%>px">
                    <%

                        for (int y = 1; y <= b3_tube; y++) {%>
                    <div id="b3tube_<%out.print(y);%>" class="tube" style="margin-top: <%


                          if (y == 1) {
                            out.print((b3_tube_sec_height / 2)+b_tot_height+30);
                        } else {
                            out.print((b3_tube_sec_height));
                        }


                         %>px"></div>
                    <% }%>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can I show the DIV if and only if b3 is not null? Any JSP test condition?

Comment: It's better to post HTML, not a asp template.

Comment: you mean whole html?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(b3 != null){
//put type_b div here
}
```

It will only render what's in the if statement if it's true, so if b3 is not null, then it'll show. If you have a variable containing b3's value, then you can do this. You didn't put enough information but from what is gathered though, here's my shot in the dark answer.